# Python isalnum() method is working weirdly?

Tags: python

I want to get no of strings, no of numbers and no of alpha numerics from the given string. Below is my working python logic for it.

```
def sentence(sentence):
    numCount = 0
    alphaCount = 0
    alphaNumCount = 0
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    print(sentence)
    for word in sentence:
        print(word, type(word))
        if word.isnumeric():
            numCount += 1
        elif word.isalpha():
            alphaCount += 1
        elif word.isalnum():
            alphaNumCount += 1
    return [numCount, alphaNumCount, alphaCount]

print(sentence("OK 12 7 1A A1 B2C3 Hello Aha A80"))
// expecting: [2, 4, 3]
// output: [2, 4, 3]
```

But initially I have used `elif word.isalnum():` as 2nd conditional check and `elif word.isalpha():` as a 3rd conditional check. The `isalnum()` method says it returns true if string is alpha numeric false otherwise, but it is not working as it says. It is returning true for complete string as well.
Below is my initial code. Python version in my system is `3.10.6`.

```
def sentence(sentence):
    numCount = 0
    alphaCount = 0
    alphaNumCount = 0
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    print(sentence)
    for word in sentence:
        print(word, type(word))
        if word.isnumeric():
            numCount += 1
        elif word.isalnum(): // not working. "Ok" -> True 
            alphaNumCount += 1
        elif word.isalpha():
            alphaCount += 1
    return [numCount, alphaNumCount, alphaCount]

print(sentence("OK 12 7 1A A1 B2C3 Hello Aha A80"))
// expecting: [2, 4, 3]
// output: [2, 7, 0]
```

Please let me know whats the problem.

Comment: alphanumeric includes strings that are all letters - alphanumeric does not mean just a combination of letters and numbers --> it means all numbers or all letters or a combination of both.

Comment: In order for your code to work properly as you are expecting, you should swap the order of `isalpha()` and `isalnum()`.

Comment: All of your strings are *alphanumeric*. See `help str.isalnum`

Comment: `"OK".isalnum()` is true because the string `"OK"` only contains alphabetic characters or numeric characters. it is equivalent to `str.isalpha() or str.isnumeric()`

Comment: Switch the second two conditions

Comment: @Ryan I deleted my comment, but I thin k the point still stands that all that code could be replaced by simply asking "Why does `"OK". isalnum()` return `True`" instead of burying that information in a "comment" (which isn't really a comment, rather, it just renders the code syntactically incorrect)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, agreed. No worries.

Comment: For complete string like "Ok" isalnum() is returning True that too only when I use it as a 2nd conditonal check as mentioned in the 2nd code block above. It is returning False correctly when I put isalnum() check in the 3rd place. Thats where I'm feeling weird. Please check above once. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @PremchandK no, it isn't returning false there. It just *never makes it to that condition because an earlier condition is true*. This is because `isalnum` is a superset of `isalpha` and `isnumeric`

Comment: Thank you all. I got why it is working like that by above comments. I'm a beginner in python, but feeling like isalnum() implementation or name of it not went right way. Sorry if I talked wrong.